# google.maps.places.Autocomplete not working using SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a location search and form auto fill using google.maps.places.Autocomplete.

It is working right accessing the html directly (file:///location.html), but is not working using python SimpleHTTPServer to serve the html (http://localhost:8000/location.html).

Accessing the html using localhost, the search input loads correctly, but shows no result. No suggestion is presented.

**Html code**

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  function initialize(){
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var options = {types: ['(cities)']};
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var search_result = {};
      components = place.address_components;
      for (i in components){
        var name = components[i].types[0];
        search_result[name] = components[i].long_name;
        search_result[name + "_short"] = components[i].short_name;
      }
      var city = search_result.locality;
      var state = search_result.administrative_area_level_1;
      var country = search_result.country_short;
      document.getElementById('city').value = city;
      document.getElementById('state').value = state;
      document.getElementById('country').value = country;
    });
  };
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50"></br></br>
<input id="city" type="text" size="50" disabled="disabled"></br></br>
<input id="state" type="text" size="50" disabled="disabled"></br></br>
<input id="country" type="text" size="50" disabled="disabled">
</body>
</html>
```

**Python command**

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: @J_Everhart383, no error log.
Apparently the autocomplete initializes correctly, the input receives the placeholder 'Enter the location'. However, no suggestion is presented while typing.

Comment: Is there some security config to allow google suggestions?

Comment: If there is not error in the JS console, then it isn't a browser security issue. Check in the network tab of dev tools as you start typing in a place. If the tool is actually initialized, you should see some results returned via AJAX calls. There also might be more info if those network calls are an error. I can't see your CSS, but also double check the input has explicit width. It needs that to append list of suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @J_Everhart383, I checked the network logs and found the problem: 
`"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console."`

The API works disabled for tests, but you must enable it to use in production. I thought it was already active.

Comment: Ah-ha. That's great. I've dealt with that issue a few times, but each time I can never remember the exact issue. I'm going to add the summary of these comments as an answer. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with the Google Maps Places Autocomplete dropdown. There are a few things to check.

First, make sure that you have an explicit width set on the input element you want to use to append the place suggestions. Google Maps needs this to correctly affix the divs that contain suggestions as they are populated.

If that isn't your issue, and you aren't seeing any error in the JS console, open the network tab of your dev tools and watch the network requests that happen as you type into the input.

You should see a number of AJAX calls that should either contain suggestions, or additional error messages that you can use for debugging. One common error message has to do with the configuration of Google Maps permissions in the Developers Console:

```
"This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console."
```

If this is the case, you will need to go enable API access for the API key you pass in the initialization of the Google library.